# how to make checkbox clicked just one time in 24?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I did a list of checkbox and i want to make every checkbox clickable only one time in 24 hours and then return to the normal case.

thank's for help

Comment: Do asking about pure front end solution?
Or do you want to keep their state in server.
Please be more specific about resetting strategy.

Comment: Explain more your stack; do you control the server side if there is one? What's the link between your server and client (websocket, etc)?

A simple answer would be to make a setTimeout of 24hours when you click on one checkbox, disable the checkbox then after the timeout pass enable the checkbox again. But if you want the state to remain you need a server side solution.

Comment: thank's for replay gkucmierz i ask about front end solution .

Comment: thank's mr  Eldynn i will try your solution

Comment: You could use a flag stored in a cookie that expires after 24 hours and enable.disable the checkbox based on the flag. This works even after page refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the below example following are the actions:

- After 24Hrs both the checkboxes will be enabled.
- Once you select any of the checkbox the checkboxes will be disabled again and will be
  activated after 24 Hrs.

```js
let timeInterval = null;
let timerInHr = 86400000 //24Hr convereted into milliseconds;;

function enableAll(isDisabled) {
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach((elem) => {
    elem.disabled = isDisabled === undefined ? false : true;
  })
}
enableAll(false);

function setTimer() {
  timeInterval = setTimeout(() => {
    enableAll();
  }, timerInHr);
}
setTimer();
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach((elem) => {

  elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
    enableAll(false);
    setTimer();
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="day1" value="day1"><label for="day1">Day1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="day2" value="day2"><label for="day2">Day2</label>
```

Comment: It should be noted that refreshing the page will re-enable the checkboxes since the reset state isn't stored in e.g. `localStorage`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const checkEl = document.querySelector('.check');
const nextEl = document.querySelector('.next');

const block = doit => {
  checkEl.checked = doit;
  checkEl.disabled = doit;
};

const next = () => block(false);

nextEl.addEventListener('click', next);
checkEl.addEventListener('change', () => block(true));

setInterval(next, 1e3 * 60 * 60);
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
  Check it
</label>

<p>
  <input type="button" class="next" value="next 1 hour" />
  Release by click or every 1 hour:
</p>
```

Check out this solution. It may be helpfull.